# How to replace every character from input? (python3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I have to replace a text by a text which is turned 180°, by replacing these:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ?!.-()<>%$',:_/\
```

by

```
ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞ˥ɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀qƆpƎℲפHIſʞ˥WNOԀΌɹS┴∩ΛMX⅄Z0ƖᄅƐㄣϛ9ㄥ86 ¿¡˙-)(><%$,':‾\/
```

I started typing `.replace('','')` for every character but their must be an easier way?

Comment: Is there any logic behind this replacing?

Comment: the output has to be the input, turned 180°.

Comment: It's just one of the excercises for programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), using the static [`str.maketrans()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to build the translation table from your two strings:

```
transmap = str.maketrans(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ?!.-()<>%$',:_/\\",
    "ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞ˥ɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀qƆpƎℲפHIſʞ˥WNOԀΌɹS┴∩ΛMX⅄Z0ƖᄅƐㄣϛ9ㄥ86 ¿¡˙-)(><%$,':‾\\/")

result = inputstring.translate(transmap)
```

Demo:

```
>>> transmap = str.maketrans(
...     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ?!.-()<>%$',:_/\\",
...     "ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞ˥ɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀qƆpƎℲפHIſʞ˥WNOԀΌɹS┴∩ΛMX⅄Z0ƖᄅƐㄣϛ9ㄥ86 ¿¡˙-)(><%$,':‾\\/")
>>> 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, 42 times!'.translate(transmap)
"┴ɥǝ bnᴉɔʞ qɹoʍu ɟox ɾnɯds oʌǝɹ ʇɥǝ ˥ɐzʎ poƃ' ㄣᄅ ʇᴉɯǝs¡"
```

You may want to *reverse* the result as well; you can use the `[::-1]` slice for that:

```
>>> 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, 42 times!'.translate(transmap)[::-1]
"¡sǝɯᴉʇ ᄅㄣ 'ƃop ʎzɐ˥ ǝɥʇ ɹǝʌo sdɯnɾ xoɟ uʍoɹq ʞɔᴉnb ǝɥ┴"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly but for some reason i can only accept it as an answer in 5 min?

Comment: @Jan-PieterVanParys It's there to give others time to answer. There might be a better solution than the first one, so it's often a good idea to wait a few minutes if someone has something else to offer! Although in this case `str.translate()` is pretty much the go-to solution